# Who is/are lecturing

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the following sentence correct?

'Hey John, look who is/are lecturing us on not making fun of anyone.'

Note that there is more than one person lecturing us. 'Is' or 'are' : Which one should I use?

Comment: "**Who is lecturing**" is better even with more than one person.

Comment: For *who is/are.....* It depends on what the speaker and the listener know.